# GWT editors: show ConstraintViolations AND EditorErrors

Tags: gwt, bean-validation, gwt-editors

I'm having a hard time to achieve that GWT editors show possible `ConstraintViolation`s and `EditorError`s at the same time. It's no problem to either show the errors or the validation violations.

The following example uses some `number` field of an `Entity`

Entity.java:

```
....
@NotNull
private Integer number;

public Integer getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public void setNumber(Integer number) {
    this.number = number;
}
...
```

EntityEditor.ui.xml

```
...
<editor:ValueBoxEditorDecorator ui:field="number">
    <editor:valuebox>
        <g:IntegerBox />
    </editor:valuebox>
</editor:ValueBoxEditorDecorator>
...
```

EntityEditor.java

```
...
@UiField
ValueBoxEditorDecorator<Integer> number;
private Validator fValidator;
private EntityEditorDriver fEditorDriver;
...
public void validate() {
    Entity entity = fEditorDriver.flush();
    Set<ConstraintViolation<Entity>> violations = fValidator.validate(entity);
    if (!violations.isEmpty() || fEditorDriver.hasErrors()) {
        fEditorDriver.setConstraintViolations(violations);
    } else {
        // process the entity
    }
}
```

When I call `validate()` without entering anything in the number box the message "Cannot be empty." is correctly displayed. Calling `validate()` with "asdf" I expect to see both messages "Cannot be empty." and "Bad value (asdf)", but only the first one is shown. The editor error is shown when I don't call `setConstraintViolations()` but obviously no validation violations will be shown.

What am I missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to `getErrors()` and merge them with your constraint violations (implementing a `ConstraintViolation` that wraps an `EditorError`)

Comment: Thanks, that's my current workaround. Was hoping for another solution.

Comment: I'd suggest filing a request for enhancement to add a `toConstraintViolation()` method to `EditorError` to make the process easier.